# Is possible add an additional button to the node in a cytoscape.js chart?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

Is possible add an additional button to the node in a cytoscape.js chart?
Like this:

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: what layout are you using to get the branched edges in this image? I need something similar.

Comment: Looking for a solution to this as well. I think it should be possible to use overlays and play around with "Layers" and "node-html-label" cytoscape extensions

Answer (score -2):

If you want to create overlays, you can use or create an extension: http://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions